# Como ler stdin em python?

Tags: python-3.x, linux

Utilizando o netcat para monitorar uma determinada porta em meu dispositivo, usando o terminal de comando do shell, posso verificar os dados recebidos por ela e enviar dados de volta para o dispositivo conectado, assim como por exemplo, faz um sistema de chat com sockets. O meu questionamento é, com replicar o mesmo comportamento de "iteratividade" em python?

Com o que consegui desenvolver até então, eu posso receber os dados e verificá-los, mas ainda não sou capaz enviar algo de volta (usando `stdin`, que suponho ser a maneira para isso).

```
from threading import Thread
import os
import time
import subprocess

class netcat(Thread):
    def __init__(self):

        Thread.__init__(self)

        self.cmd  = ['sudo nc -l -p 12']
        self.proc = subprocess.Popen(self.cmd, shell = True,
                                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                     stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                                     stdin=subprocess.PIPE)

        self.output = self.proc.stdout.read().decode('utf-8')
        self.error  = self.proc.stderr.read().decode('utf-8')
        #self.intput = self.proc.stdin.write("y\r")

    def run(self):

        while True:

            time.sleep(1)

            print("out: " + self.output)
            print("err: " + self.error )
            #print("in : " + self.input )

            if self.output == 'send':
                self.proc.stdin.write("ok")
nc = netcat()
nc.start()
```

Agradeço.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Resolvido. Para que eu fosse capaz de replicar o comportamento que obtive usando o shell e ser capaz de tanto ler quanto responder ao que era escrito na porta, tive de acessa-la através de dois processos diferentes. Para que seja possível comprovar e servir ao próximo, desenvolvi um código de teste que responde com um `"ok"` caso receba o dado que espera na porta.

```
import subprocess    

cmd  = ['sudo nc -l -p 2000']

while True:

    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell = True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    out  = proc.stdout.read().decode('utf-8')    

    if out == 'enviado':        

        while True:
            proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell = True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
            proc.stdin.write(b'ok')
            proc.stdin.flush()
            proc.stdin.close()            
            break
```